# Can't emit an event from method called through event bus (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, event-bus, emit

I have a "table" parent component containing any number of "row" child components which themselves contain input fields. Submitting the whole table from parent component gathers data from all rows and validates them.

To do that, parent component' submit button uses an event bus to execute a method called `processRow()` from each row / child component:

Parent' submit button:

```
methods: {
  parentTableSubmit () {
    EventBus.$emit('processRow');
  }
}
```

This method must then send validation results + form data back to table / parent component. I use a regular `$emit` for that:

Row / child component:

```
mounted () {
  EventBus.$on('processRow', this.processRow);
},
methods: {
  processRow () {
    // validation code ...
    this.$emit("rowData", data);
  }
}
```

Table / parent component listens to `rowData` event because it calls children / row components this way:

```
<div
  v-for="(row, i) in rows"
  :key="i"
  @rowData="getRowData"
>
```

And here's the corresponding parent's method:

```
methods: {
  getRowData (data) {
    console.log('data from row:')
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Well, `getRowData()` never gets executed.

Parent' submit button successfully executes the `processRow()` method from inside all child components. But they fail to execute in return `getRowData()` from parent component.

why? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code has `@rowData="getRowData"` on a `<div>`. That event listener needs to be on the element that creates the child component, not a `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it. It's embarrassing, I keep making this kind of careless mistake that make me waste hours sometimes. Am I the only one is this silly situation?

Comment: Little mistakes like this are common, everybody makes them. The key is being able to debug them quickly. Isolating the point where the expected behaviour breaks down is an important skill, but on this occasion you seem to have done all the hard work. You'd narrowed down the problem scope nicely, I can't really speculate about why you didn't make that last step. You may want to reflect on that yourself, as well as pondering how you made the mistake in the first place. Perhaps there's an important lesson to learn, perhaps not. Either way you're better placed to spot a similar mistake next time.